# Update con case actualiza registros a null

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente sp, para actualizar el valor de una columna en base al valor de otra.
El problema es que agrego valores una primer vez actualizo esos valores con ese sp, pero despues vuelvo a insertar nuevos valores vuelvo a realizar la actualización y es aqui donde los registros que ya fueron actualizados son actualizados nuevamente pero como null, como le puedo indicar a la consulta que solamente actualice si el valor Left, Right, a, c, v o Delete si no es ninguno de estos entonces omita hacer una actualización null.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEvent]
AS
    UPDATE Event 
SET nameEvent = CASE
    WHEN nameEvent ='Left' THEN 'MouseLeft' 
    WHEN nameEvent ='Right' THEN 'MouseRight'
    WHEN nameEvent ='a' THEN 'Ctrl+a' 
    WHEN nameEvent ='c' THEN 'Ctrl+c' 
    WHEN nameEvent ='v' THEN 'Ctrl+v' 
    WHEN nameEvent ='Delete' THEN 'DeleteText'
  END 
WHERE nameControl = 'Mouse' or nameControl = 'KeyUp'
```

De antemano gracias.

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el caso por defecto. Si no es ninguno de esos valores entonces que mantenga su valor actual.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEvent]
    AS
        UPDATE Event 
    SET nameEvent = CASE
        WHEN nameEvent ='Left' THEN 'MouseLeft' 
        WHEN nameEvent ='Right' THEN 'MouseRight'
        WHEN nameEvent ='a' THEN 'Ctrl+a' 
        WHEN nameEvent ='c' THEN 'Ctrl+c' 
        WHEN nameEvent ='v' THEN 'Ctrl+v' 
        WHEN nameEvent ='Delete' THEN 'DeleteText'
        ELSE nameEvent
      END 
    WHERE nameControl = 'Mouse' or nameControl = 'KeyUp'
```

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado.
DS @Lobos